# Call another field inside preprocess_views_view_field

Tags: views, 8, theming

how can I access the value of another field inside the preprocess_views_view_field.
This is an example:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $field = $variables['field'];

  if ($view->id() == 'VIEW_NAME' && $view->current_display == 'DISPLAY_NAME') {
    if ($field->field == 'FIELD_NAME') {
      $my_output = manipulation(ANOTHER_FIELD_NAME_IN_VIEW);
      $variables['output'] = $my_output;
    }
  }
}
```

It's possible or should i use it _preprocess_views_view?

Comment: Have a look in `$variables['row']` that should contain all the fields in your view

Comment: Should be you can see it here https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/8.8.x you can see $variables['row'] being used

Comment: I am using _preprocess_views_view_field single with no final s. Maybe it's not possible.

Comment: Ok, I solved, thanks your suggestion helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,
I solved it like this:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $field = $variables['field'];
  $rows = $variables['rows'];

  if ($view->id() == 'VIEW_NAME' && $view->current_display == 'DISPLAY_NAME') {
    if ($field->field == 'FIELD_NAME') {      
      foreach ($view->field as $fieldId => $field) {
        if ($fieldId === 'ANOTHER_FIELD_NAME_IN_VIEW') {
          $my_output = $view->style_plugin->getFieldValue($row->index, $fieldId);
        }
      }
      $variables['output'] = $my_output;
    }
  }
}
```